# Stop Children Mocking in Moq/AutoFixture

Tags: c#, mocking, moq, autofixture

I am having a problem where either moq or Ploeh.AutoFixture.AutoMoq is mocking all the children interfaces when in one case I want one of them to be null.

I am using Npoc and it has an Interface called IDatabase

```
 public interface IDatabase : IDatabaseQuery
    {
        IDbConnection Connection { get; }
        IDbTransaction Transaction { get; }

        void AbortTransaction();
        void BeginTransaction();
        void BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel? isolationLevel);
        void CompleteTransaction();
        IDataParameter CreateParameter();
        int Delete(object poco);
        int Delete<T>(object pocoOrPrimaryKey);
        int Delete<T>(Sql sql);
        int Delete<T>(string sql, params object[] args);
        int Delete(string tableName, string primaryKeyName, object poco);
        int Delete(string tableName, string primaryKeyName, object poco, object primaryKeyValue);
        void Dispose();
        Transaction GetTransaction();
        Transaction GetTransaction(IsolationLevel? isolationLevel);
        object Insert(object poco);
        object Insert(string tableName, string primaryKeyName, object poco);
        object Insert(string tableName, string primaryKeyName, bool autoIncrement, object poco);
        void Save(object poco);
        void Save(string tableName, string primaryKeyName, object poco);
        IDatabase SetTransaction(IDbTransaction tran);
        int Update(object poco);
        int Update<T>(Sql sql);
        int Update(object poco, IEnumerable<string> columns);
        int Update(object poco, object primaryKeyValue);
        int Update<T>(string sql, params object[] args);
        int Update(object poco, object primaryKeyValue, IEnumerable<string> columns);
        int Update(string tableName, string primaryKeyName, object poco);
        int Update(string tableName, string primaryKeyName, object poco, IEnumerable<string> columns);
        int Update(string tableName, string primaryKeyName, object poco, object primaryKeyValue);
        int Update(string tableName, string primaryKeyName, object poco, object primaryKeyValue, IEnumerable<string> columns);
    }
```

I don't want  `IDbTransaction Transaction { get; }` to be mocked as I want it to be null but it is getting mocked.

I then also have a IUnitOfWork that has the IDatabase interface in it.

```
  public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable 
    {
        void Commit();
        IDatabase Db { get; }
        void SetOneTimeCommandTimeout(int timeout);
        void SetGlobalCommandTimeout(int timeout);
        void BeginTransaction();

    }
```

// code

```
 fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
 fixture.Freeze<Mock<IDatabase>>();
 var test = fixture.CreateAnonymous<MyService>();
```

Since Transaction is a readonly property I don't know how to set it back to null.

Comment: That... is a very.... fat.... interface. You sure you can't simplify that bad boy a bit?

Comment: Not my code. It is from NPoc what is a ORM. So no I really don't want to touch it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
  fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
  var mock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IDatabase>>();
  mock.SetupGet(o => o.Transaction).Returns((IDbTransaction)null);
  var test = fixture.CreateAnonymous<MyService>();
```

Comment: hmm not sure did not seem to work. Like it gets set to null but then when I actually use "test.MyMethod" and go into that method and I look at the Transaction it is all of a sudden mocked up again. I edited my posted and added one more piece of code that may or may not help.

Comment: @chobo2 is MyService using IDatabase or IUnitOfWork?

Comment: I figured it out I had to manually "setup" the method that returns the unitofWork to return the the unitOfWork that had the mocked database which had the null transaction.